# Emacs Company-Mode: Don't complete if text at point equals 'end'

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I use a lot of ruby, and the worst part of my workflow is how company-mode will try and complete keywords like 'end'. I've googled and read the code, but I can't find anything to help me fix this. I'm using company-tabnine primarily now, but have had this issue on other company backends for ruby. I welcome hacky solutions. Relevant config below. Thanks!

```
(use-package company
  :init (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
  :config
  (global-company-mode 1))

(use-package company-tabnine
  :config
  (add-to-list 'company-backends #'company-tabnine)
  (setq company-idle-delay 0.05)
  (setq company-show-numbers t)
  (company-tng-configure-default)
  (setq company-frontends
        '(company-tng-frontend
          company-pseudo-tooltip-frontend
          company-echo-metadata-frontend))
  )
```

Comment: while you *could* filter company completion in general, a better solution would apply to a specific backend - for example with `company-keywords` it is simply a matter of removing "end" from the candidates

Comment: I don't use tabnine, but by the looks up of it, it doesn't do language-specific completion? Or, have you integrated with another ruby backend, eg. robe or lsp?

Comment: hmmm, maybe if i made a wrapper around the backend that did this logic.... that might be a sufficiently hacky solution. 

i was hoping company would have a way, but leaving it entirely up to the backend makes sense

Comment: the main company function just manages calling all the backends in turn, so without apply a general filter to the main company function, I would imagine a solution would *probably* depend on hacking a given backend, unless the backend could already be configured to do this, eg. `company-keywords`